# How do I use a channel receiver inside a nested closure?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust

I want to share some data between an async function with another async function running on a separate thread. In this case it's a cronjob.

This is the solution I've come up with so far:

`main.rs`

```rust
use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use tokio::task;
use tokio_cron_scheduler::{Job, JobScheduler};


#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
  let (tx, mut rx): (mpsc::Sender<i16>, mpsc::Receiver<i16>) = mpsc::channel(1000);

  task::spawn(async {
    let mut sched = JobScheduler::new();
    let job = Job::new_async("0 0/5 * * * *", |_uuid, _l| {
      Box::pin(async move {
        let devices = rx.recv().await.unwrap();
        api::insert_datapoint(devices).await;
      })
    }).unwrap();

    sched.add(job).expect("failed adding job to scheduler");
    sched.start().await.expect("failed starting scheduler");
  });
}
```

but I'm getting an error preventing me from doing so

```
cannot move out of `rx`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
move out of `rx` occurs here (E0507)
```

Is there a way to solve this? Is my approach of using a channel for this task inherently wrong?

EDIT:
I've tried adding the `move` keyword to the outermost closure, however this results in the same error

Adding a `move` before `|_uuid, _l|` does not make any difference either

Comment: Yes I've tried to do so. It gives me another error
```
cannot move out of `rx`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
move out of `rx` occurs here (E0507)
```

Comment: Also, please always include the full error.

Comment: I wonder why the compiler doesn't add it itself, but `move |...|` should work.

Comment: `move |...|` do not work because it is FnMut, that closure it is supposed to be used many times, so it cannot ensure that the first one will be finished before it launches the next. I belive it will have to use some sync wrapping over the channel.

Comment: `mpsc` isn't designed to have multiple receivers. `mpsc` = multi-producer, single-consumer. Even if you could make this work with a tokio-compatible mutex, you'd be better off using an `mpmc` channel. With such a channel you could just clone the receiver before the `async` block and move the clone into it. If you really want to use `mpsc` then you should have a single task awaiting the channel and spawning received sub-tasks onto their own futures.

Comment: On second glance it looks like you have the `rx` and `tx` sides mixed up... it seems like a really weird use-case to receive a single message from a channel on a schedule. Usually you'd want to _send_ a single message on a schedule and have a long-running task receiving the messages.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting it working thanks to cdhowie's suggestion

```rust
use tokio::task;
use tokio_cron_scheduler::{Job, JobScheduler};


#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
  let (tx, rx): (async_channel::Sender<i16>, async_channel::Receiver<i16>) = async_channel::bounded(1000);

  task::spawn(async {
    let mut sched = JobScheduler::new();
    let job = Job::new_async("0 0/5 * * * *", |_uuid, _l| {
    let rx = rx.clone();
      Box::pin(async move {
        if let Ok(devices) = rx.recv.await {
          api::insert_datapoint(devices).await;
        }
      })
    }).unwrap();

    sched.add(job).expect("failed adding job to scheduler");
    sched.start().await.expect("failed starting scheduler");
  });
}
```